# Can you program a button in jupyter notebook to run another notebook's program?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Upon pressing on the Left Flexion button from the User Interface notebook, it will automatically run the program from Left Flexion notebook. Will that be possible ?
[image]

Comment: Yes. Though this is too wide question to be answered as it stands. Please add more details.